# How does this code work to find the largest of three numbers without using any comparison operator?

Tags: algorithm

Here is the function that finds the greater of two numbers:

```
int larger(int a,int b)
{
    int c=a-b;
    int k=c>>31&1;
    int max=a-k*c;
    return max;
 }
```

To find the greatest of three numbers, call it such as:

```
larger(a,larger(b,c));
```

How does this work?

Comment: Note, this works for Java and C#.  It *might* work for C and C++, but shifting a negative number is technically undefined behavior for those two.  Don't blame anyone but yourself if a demon flies out of your nose.

Comment: The behavior is implementation-defined, not undefined. Nose-demons will not be observed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
int c=a-b;
```

`c`will be negative if `a < b` else it will positive. Now a negative number will have its most significant bit(MSB) set.

```
int k=c>>31&1;
```

This step assumes that `sizeof(int)` is `4` bytes and extracts the MSB of `c` in `k`. So `k` is either `0` or `1`

```
int max=a-k*c;
```

replacing `c = a-b` in this we get `max = a-k*(a-b)`. So when

```
k = 0, max = a-0*(a-b)
           = a

k = 1, max = a-1*(a-b)
           = b
```

Comment: `c` will be negative when `a<b` IF AND ONLY IF `a-b` doesn't result in a signed integer overflow (that is, when the `a-b` is mathematically negative but `c` receives a positive value because of being to short to contain the correct sign bit of the difference in bit 31, when it needs to be at least 33-bit long). Also, signed integer overflows fall into the category of undefined behavior in C/C++, although in practice most of the time it's OK. Right shifts of negative (or is it signed?) integers is also undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5):

This only works for 32-bit integers, of course.

`k=c>>31&1` isolates the sign bit, which is 0 or 1.

If `k` is 0, then `a>=b` and `max = a - 0*(a-b) = a`.

If `k` is 1, then `a<b` and `max = a - 1*(a-b) = a-a+b = b`.

Historically, instruction pipelining was the main reason for using code that avoids an `if` test.  If the pipeline is deep and the processor doesn't use branch prediction, a half-dozen integer operations can take less time to do than the time lost due to pipeline refilling and dealing with speculative stores, if any.  With branch prediction, code with an `if` (or equivalent) might be faster.  Either way, the cost of the nanoseconds saved or lost might never exceed the program-maintainance costs for that code.

Answer (score -3):

try this.. it is lengthy, sorry :P

```
while(x && y && z)
{
        x--;y--;z--;c++;
}


if(x && y)
{
while(x && y)
{
    x--;y--;c++;
}
if(x) c+=x;
if(y) c+=y;
}


if(z && y)
{   
while(z && y)
{
    z--;y--;c++;
}
if(z) c+=z;
if(y) c+=y;
}

if(x && z)
{
while(x && z)
{
    x--;z--;c++;
}
if(x) c+=x;
if(z) c+=z;
}

return c;
```